# Finding The Nth element Of a General Type in SCALA Throws NoSuchElementException

Tags: scala, exception

In the following code:

```
object example {

  trait List[T] {
    def isEmpty: Boolean

    def head: T

    def tail: List[T]
  }

  class Cons[T](val head: T, val tail: List[T]) extends List[T] {
    def isEmpty: Boolean = false
  }

  class Nil[T] extends List[T] {
    def isEmpty: Boolean = true

    val head: Nothing = throw new NoSuchElementException("Nil.head")
    val tail: Nothing = throw new NoSuchElementException("Nil.tail")

  }


  def nth[T](n: Int, xs: List[T]): T =
    if (xs.isEmpty) throw new IndexOutOfBoundsException("Out of Bound")
    else if (n == 0) xs.head
    else nth(n - 1, xs.tail)

  val list = new Cons(1, new Cons(2, new Cons(3, new Nil)))
  nth(2,list) //should return 3

}
```

I tried to define a general trait `List[T]` so later I can give it any type. I could implement my classes from it and then later I defined a function which takes an integer and a list and returns the element located at the nth given index. `val list = new Cons(1, new Cons(2, new Cons(3, new Nil)))` throws `NoSuchElementException`. I think my code has a fundamental issue and I can figure it out. 
By the way I'm running it the REPL.Thank you.

Comment: I have updated your code and will get back soon

Comment: I have updated my answer lucky also the other guy have also answered this as well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please correct your following lines from

```
val head: Nothing = throw new NoSuchElementException("Nil.head")
val tail: Nothing = throw new NoSuchElementException("Nil.tail")
```

to

```
def head: Nothing = throw new NoSuchElementException("Nil.head")
def tail: Nothing = throw new NoSuchElementException("Nil.tail")
```

Comment: Yeah, I missed it when I copied and paste the code, but I still get the same error

Answer (score 1):

In `Nil`, you define `head` and `tail` as `val`, so those statements are executed at the time that you instantiate a `Nil`, resulting in the error.

Change them to `def head: Nothing = ...` and `def tail: Nothing = ...`